# mysql varchar field is returned as integer

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am trying to get contact details from a database by sending an ajax request to the servers where it gets the details form the database. For some reason it returns integers but the one field is `tinytext` and the other is a `varchar`. Please help.

Here is my code:

```
$user = $_GET['user'];
$json = '{"details":[';
$sql = "SELECT cdType, cdDetail FROM tbcontactdetails WHERE User_ID = $user";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if(gettype($result) == 'object') {
    if($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())    
            $json += $row['cdDetail'];
        $json += ']}';
        echo  gettype($json);
    }   
}
else
    echo $conn->error;
```

As you can see I return the datatype of $json, it returns integer, cdType is a `tinytext` and cdDetail is a `varchar` of size `50`.

And this is my ajax request, not that I think the problem lies there because it is working reliably:

```
$.get("./profileChange.php", {user: ses_user, type: "loadCont"}, function(result) {
        alert("Debug: " + result);
    });
```

Comment: `WHERE User_ID = $user` is a string.. `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())` a missing `{` and `}` perhaps?

Comment: You are turning it into an integer by doing `$json +=`. You need to change to `$json .=`. see http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php to see the difference between `+=` and `.=`

Comment: Lol now I feel so stupid, I did not realise that

Answer (score 1):

An invalid query string syntax along with a improper way of concatenation.

Change this:

```
$sql = "SELECT cdType, cdDetail FROM tbcontactdetails WHERE User_ID = $user";
```

to this:

```
$sql = "SELECT cdType, cdDetail FROM tbcontactdetails WHERE User_ID = '$user'";
```

Either remove the `while` before this:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
```

to this:

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Or give the proper opening and closing braces:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { /* your code */ }
```

And this:

```
 $json += $row['cdDetail'];
```

to this:

```
 $json .= $row['cdDetail'];
```

[PHP Manual: Assignment Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php)